# Maclaurin Series for a function undefined at a point.

Tags: taylor-expansion

Let's say I want a power series representation for the function

$\ln \left(\dfrac{x^2-9}{4-x^2}\right)$

at $c=0$. How would one go about this? I have acquired the second, third and fourth terms, but I am struggling getting the first term since f(0) is undefined.

Comment: This function has no definition near $x=0$. It is not differentiable at $x=0$, not to say the higher order derivatives. Why do you think there exists a power series for the function at that point? What "second term" did you get?

Comment: As a real valued function, this is undefined for any $|x| \le 2$. As a complex-valued function, you can define it everywhere on the complex plane except for $x \in [-2,2]$. But that restriction still precludes you from having a power series about $x = 2$. Indeed, you can't even have a Laurent series at that point or about $-2$.